# Are the contents of item crates in Code Name: S.T.E.A.M. fixed?

Tags: code-name-steam

During battle, maps have breakable S.T.E.A.M. crates that have either health or steam canisters inside. Do these crates always have the same item inside? In other words, if a crate drops health the first time I play a mission, will breaking that same crate drop health again if I replay the mission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, breaking a specific crate dropped the same item when I replayed a level.

A crate that dropped a health pack on my first playthrough dropped a heath pack again I replayed the level. The same applied to crates containing air canisters.